# replace image (by clicking on image)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to do something like this. After click on image I want to choose another image for upload replace on server and dynamic display new one.

Thank you for any tip.

Comment: Are you expecting the page to refresh after the upload? Or do you want some AJAX-like experience?

Comment: Yes with ajax based solution. To replace this image dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("img").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "http://example.com/someImage.gif");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but first I have to upload new image then I can use this code.

Comment: Oh, you just need a file input: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp.

Comment: Yes but I want to run this after click on image. Is the only answer is ajax form or maybe there is plugin.

Comment: You could always popup a file input when they click the image, or unhide one that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
<img src="current_image.jpg" onclick="javascript:this.src='new_image.jpg';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you try using a upload form and send the upload to a hidden iframe... add a listener to this iframe to check when the file is complete upload... and retrieve the url of the new image and update the src of the img element